# Why will some pages having the same footer include links redirect different?

Tags: php, url, hyperlink, duplicates, directory

Basically I've got pages with a header and footer include, linking to other pages on the main level folder "2015website". Inside the 2015website folder is another folder titled "pick_style". In that folder is a page that has the same exact includes as the pages on the main folder level, except it redirects differently. It will add an extra "2015website" to each link in the url.

Now if I simply just change the header and footer include links and delete the 2015website folder in the link's source, it will fix it for that page, but then breaks it on the main level pages. I'm using php if that has anything to do with it. But I don't know why it's doing that. I need help!

Comment: at a guess your urls in the links are relative, instead of absolute

Comment: Add a leading slash to the link to make it absolute, like so: href="/thelink.html"